# Vaadin: after upgrading to v23.0.1 (from 22.0.2): Error with Binder opening a Form

Tags: vaadin

After upgrading to Vaadin 23.0.x (from former 22.0.2) I now keep getting the following error when opening a certain dialog:

```
2022-08-01 18:56:25,977 ERROR [http-nio-8085-exec-5] net.mmo.utils.kism.ui.views.nodes.NodeView: java.lang.IllegalStateException: All bindings created with forField must be completed before calling readBean
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.checkBindingsCompleted(Binder.java:3070)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.readBean(Binder.java:2110)
        at net.mmo.utils.kism.ui.views.nodes.NodeForm.readBean(NodeForm.java:487)
        at net.mmo.utils.kism.ui.views.nodes.NodeForm.setNode(NodeForm.java:211)
```

This dialog has worked perfectly fine since I wrote it (using version 18.0.x about 2 years ago) and up to v22.0.2. I can't make sense of that error message and I don't understand what the issue could be here. I verified that issue going back and forth and the difference is really only the Vaadin version upgrade. Before it, the dialog works just fine and after it I get the above Exception when opening it.

I also can't quite believe what I think the message is stating here: if it would indeed check that I define or complete any bindings AFTER calling Binder.readBean() - how could it know that already in that very moment, i.e. when the code calls readBean() - as indicated by the stacktrace?
If there would indeed be any bindings being defined afterwards, IMHO it could only find that out AFTER said readBean()-call, i.e. when any additional bindings were actually defined, couldn't it?

So, could someone please try to "translate" or explain that issue or the background behind it to me?

Comment: While you are binding things, you somewhere forgot to actually `bind`
a field. If you can not pinpoint the place in your code, you would have
to start by debugging into the place the exception is thrown. The Binder
has a private Map incompleteBindings, which might give you a hint...

Comment: I created me a version of class "com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder" which is a 1:1 copy of the original but - before throwing the exceptions - spits out all the entries in the `incompleteBindings` and `incompleteMemberFieldBindings`-maps. The odd thing is that it lists several fields for which I absolutely positively *do have* defined bindings! 
So I am somewhat lost at this moment what I should make out of that error... :-(

Comment: If you prefer the copy over the debugger: why not also log when the incomplete maps are added and cleaned up upon?

Comment: Actually - that's exactly what I did! I created a "debug-version" of the Binder class and using that I was able to locate all my missing bind(...)'s. There were actually several missing. Beats me, how that ever worked before. They must have changed something in this version. I faintly recall that specifying the bind(...) was optional if it would only specify the generic setters and getters with the same field name (like `binder.forField(x).bind(SomeType::getX, SomeType::setX);`. Guess, that's not valid anymore...

Comment: I would find this extremely odd if that would have worked that way. Once the binder holds a field it can hardly guess the getter/setter or property. There where recent changes, that prevent multiple-bindings (e.g. later bindings fully override previous ones).  Without you sharing the actual code, it's hard to tell, what it could have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error basically states the problem: in the process of binding a field to a property (or getter/setter in general), the finishing step of actually binding was not undertaken.  So the process was started with `.forField()` but never finished by `.bind()`.

Since the error message as of now only states the fact, but not the culprit, a developer would be in need of a debugger to inspect the private state of the `Binder`, where the map `incompleteBindings` holds the current state of the `Binder`.  The content of this map may help to find the culprit, e.g. by only holding one entry and by inspecting the flow of the program so far, that would conclude, what binding attempt failed.  Or e.g. via the included field types.

Other than plain "bugs" by the developer, there are some potential reasons, why this suddenly happens by like an update or what places to look for:

- multiple (re-)binding was recently added (e.g. to first bind "automatically" and then hand-tune the result); this holds potential, that older versions of the code just kept the initial binding and ignored the dangling second process.
- the binding process uses a builder pattern; builder must build up on the result of the previous steps.  This means, that in imperative code, there is the chance, that this chained call miss reassigning the build step.  E.g.

  ```java
  var b = binder.forField(field)
  if (predicate)
    b.asRequired() // XXX: should be `b = b.asRequired()`
  b.bind(...)
  ```

  (this may or may not be a source for this kind of problem, but it's good to point out here, since the binder builder implementation actually switche(s|d) the builder (in the past)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Meanwhile I understood and fixed the issue. If there is interest I could share my "Debug-Version" of that `Binder`-class. It contains some debug statements logging the addition & removal of entries to the `incomplete(MemberField)Bindings`-maps and lists all the remaining entries when throwing an exception. To ease identification (most components only emit names like `...TextField@54321`) I also emit the label of the component (if it is an instance of `HasLabel`). That info helped me greatly to identify the culprits! Vaadin might want to include these changes!